# Why can't D[] be used in place here?

Tags: syntax, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)

Beginner question:

Why can't I use `D[]` like that?

```
Plot[{Sin[x], D[Sin[x], x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

If I assign the result of `D[]` to a variable and put that variable in the list it works.

Comment: What about `Plot[{Sin[x], Sin'[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]`? For any function of type `f[x]` you can use `f'[x]` in place of the `D[f[x],x]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` which means in this case that `D[Sin[x], x]` isn't evaluated until after `x` is replaced with some number, so you end up with something like `D[Sin[-6.28], -6.28]` etc. which causes the errors since you can't take a derivative with respect to a number.

One way to get around this is to use `Evaluate` to evaluate the derivative before the numbers are plugged in, i.e. to do something like

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sin[x], D[Sin[x], x]}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I find it weird however why `Plot[{Sin[x], Evaluate[D[Sin[x], x]]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]` won't work. You should be able to evaluate just the `D[..]` part, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Milosz This is because `Evaluate` only works on the first level of the held expression. So for example `Hold[Evaluate[f[1+2]]]` works, but `Hold[f[Evaluate[1+2]]]` doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

Quick answer: 
The help page for plot states that "Plot has attribute HoldAll, and evaluates f only after assigning specific numerical values to x." Therefore what `D[]` effectively sees is something like `D[Sin[0.1],0.1]` (where I chose `0.1` as an arbitrary numerical value) and issues an error message that `0.1` is no valid variable. To work around that you can use `Evaluate[]` like this

```
Plot[Evaluate@{Sin[x],D[Sin[x], x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You needn't use `Evaluate`, consider using of `Derivative` instead of `D` if you don't like to use `Evaluate`. `Derivative` operates on built-in or user-defined functions and returns pure functions, e.g.

```
Derivative[#][Sin] & /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {Cos[#1] &, -Sin[#1] &, -Cos[#1] &, Sin[#1] &}
> ```

There are shortcuts for `Derivative`, e.g. `f'` or `f''` are equivalent respectively to `Derivative[1][f]` and `Derivative[2][f]`
and in your specific examples it works like this :

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Derivative[1][Sin][x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]