# PlotStyle does not work when plotting a non-evaluated list of functions

Tags: plotting, evaluation

When a list of functions is passed to `Plot` in an unevaluated form (e.g. with `Through`), the result is a plot with single color.

```
Plot[Through[{Sin, Cos, Tan}[t]], {t, 0.01, 10.5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, the same list of functions, listed explicitly, gives color as expected.

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Cos[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0.01, 10.5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`. So, it has "the right" to not work when you don't explicitly pass it a list. Try using `Evaluate@Through...`, or, better still, add the undocumented option `Evaluated->True`

Comment: @Rojo Ups ... I saw your comment after posting

Comment: @belisarius, it's ok, I wasn't going to post it, glad you did

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5

Comment: @Hypnotoad if it's a dupe I don't think it's of that one. The best answer here, assuming he's implicitly asking how and not why, is to use Evaluated, and that isn't relevant or even mentioned in the linked question

Comment: @Rojo: If it is not a dupe (and I failed to find one indeed, though I searched hard), we should emend this as the canonical Q/A for this often-asked question. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637/89

Comment: @Rojo I agree... This one is a lot closer in intent: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3935/5

Answer (score 4):

```
a[x_, y_, z_] := z; b[x_, y_, z_] := z 2; c[x_, y_, z_] := z 3;
Plot[Through[{a, b, c}[10, 3, t]], {t, 0.01, 10.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Maybe one could add here that *if* you plan to do many such plots it's also convenient to put this at the beginning of the notebook: `SetOptions[Plot,Evaluated->True];` Then you can leave out the `Evaluated` option in all the subsequent plots.