# How to change color in the plot for a given table expression?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
H[t_] = {{0, 1}, {1, t}};
tmax=5;
fun[X_?ArrayQ, t_] := -I (H[t].X - X.H[t]);

sol = NDSolve[{σ'[t] == fun[σ[t], t], σ[0] == 
Table[If[i == 1 \[And] j == 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 
  2}]}, σ[t], {t, 0, tmax}]

Flatten[Evaluate[σ[t] /. sol /. {t -> tmax/100}], 1] // MatrixForm

 Plot[Table[Flatten[Evaluate[σ[t] /. sol], 1][[i, i]], {i, 1, 2}], {t, 0,tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Table plot]

How to change the color of two lines in plot...
and why

```
Flatten[Evaluate[σ[t] /. sol], 1][[1, 1]]
```

gives

```
t
```

while

```
 Flatten[Evaluate[σ[t] /. sol], 1][[2, 2]]
```

gives

```
 {InterpolatingFuction[{{0.,5.}},<>}[t]}[[2,2]]
```

Comment: Why would you write `H[t_] = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}};` ? what is `t` doing here?

Comment: I can change H[t_] and consider that it is time dependent. You can take it like H[t_] = {{0, 1}, {1, t}};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the solutions you have derived:

```
y[x_] := Diagonal[\[Sigma][t] /. sol /. t -> x];
u[x_] := Chop[y[x][[1]]]
v[x_] := Chop[y[x][[2]]]
```

Then plotting:

```
Plot[{u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}]
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my First question...if number of evaluated functions are very large means {i,1,n}, where n considers as 20 then its very inconvenient to write in your way...

Comment: Also consider H[t] is 20 x 20 matrix...

Comment: @santosh Sorry for too narrow focus. I agree for larger systems this would be very invonvenient. In that case I would tabulete the results and use `ListPlot`. You could still use `Diagonal` to extract diagonal elements of matrix but that is up to you.

Comment: Is it possible to only evaluate Diagonal element inside the NDsolve to make it faster? something like...sol = NDSolve[{σ'[t] == fun[σ[t], t], σ[0] == 
Table[If[i == 1 \[And] j == 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 
  2}]}, Diagonal[σ[t]], {t, 0, tmax},DependentVariables-> σ[t]]

Answer (score 3):

You need to evaluate the data series separately.  E.g.

```
Plot[{
  Flatten[σ[t] /. sol, 1][[1, 1]],
  Flatten[σ[t] /. sol, 1][[2, 2]]},
 {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17299/363) for explanation.  (Your data is in an unevaluated form within `Plot`.)

**Addendum**

For the second part of your question, you have this :-

```
Flatten[Evaluate[σ[t] /. sol], 1][[1, 1]]
```

> t

Presumably you want the curve data:  `Evaluate` is unnecessary, but you need values for `t`, i.e.

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Flatten[σ[t] /. sol, 1][[1, 1]],
  {t, 0, tmax, 0.1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Further to OP's comment**

While using `Plot` would be ideal for automatic x-axis (`t`) sample intervals - i.e. more dense where `y` changes more rapidly - a suitable solution using the original function is to use a sample interval of 0.01 in `Table` and use `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`:-

```
ListLinePlot[Table[
  Flatten[σ[t] /. sol, 1][[i, i]],
  {i, 1, 2}, {t, 0, tmax, 0.01}],
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my First question...if number of evaluated functions are very large means {i,1,n}, where n considers as 20 then its very inconvenient to write in your way...

Comment: Also consider H[t] is 20 x 20 matrix...

Comment: That should work ok with `Table` and `ListLinePlot`.