# Plot derivative of integral with changing limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

My code is: `Plot[D[Integrate[E^(t*(-x^2)),{x,t+2,t^2}],t],{t,-2,3}]`.

The errors/warnings are:

`General::ivar: "-1.9999 is not a valid variable."`

`General::ivar: "-1.89786 is not a valid variable."`

`General::ivar: "-1.79582 is not a valid variable."`

`General::stop: "Further output of \!\(\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{\"General\", \"::\", \"ivar\"}], \"MessageName\"]\) will be suppressed during this calculation. "`

The graph turns out empty in the end.

What did I do wrong this time?

Comment: Use `Evaluated->True` in `Plot`.

Comment: That worked... Thanks. What does it try to do if I DON'T add this property?

Comment: If you check Plot's `Attributes` you will see that has the `HoldAll` attribute, hence the expression will remain unevaluated.

Comment: Yes, or `Plot[Evaluate@D[Integrate[E^(t*(-x^2)),{x,t+2,t^2}],t],{t,-2,3}]`. I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but too lazy to look now:)

Comment: @Spawn1701D , If I intend to plot something, in what circumstances will I want the expression to remain not evaluated...?

Comment: Same question for @Ajasja :)

Comment: When it's just a formula ($t^2$) or you give a function ($f(x)$) to name a few.

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/why-cant-d-be-used-in-place-here), which a duplicate of [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this).