# Evaluating derivatives for use in solve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I need to evaluate the derivative of a function. My function looks like

```
approx[vector_, x_] :=  Sum[vector[[n]]*Basis[n - 1, x], {n, 1, Length[vector]}]
```

and I'm defining my derivative like:

```
ddappx[vector_, x_] := D[approx[vector, x], {x, 2}]
```

However if I evaluate it at a specific x I get an error:

```
General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>
```

I searched enough to know that a solution when plotting this is to evaluate it first. Something about HoldAll and so on.

What I need to do is use it in a set of simultaneous equations. So I should be able to have:

```
Solve[{ddappx[{a,b}, 1]==0,ddappx[{a,b}, -1]==0},{a,b}]
```

To solve for {a,b} by setting the 2nd derivative of approx ==0 at x=1 and x=-1.
However I get the

```
General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>
```

Errors again. Evaluating like

```
 Solve[{Evaluate[ddappx[{a,b}, 1]]==0,Evaluate[ddappx[{a,b}, -1]]==0},{a,b}]
```

isn't working.

so, any ideas?

cheers

EDIT: Having made the suggested change, that error is solved.
However although evaluating approx works perfectly well, evaluating ddappx gives 0, no matter what I do. there is no error, just 0. I've added the whole code which goes in front just in case you think its relevant

```
diffeq[y_, x_] := y''[x] + y[x]
f[x_] := Cos[2*x]
Basis[n_, x_] := ChebyshevT[n, x]
approx[vector_, x_] := Sum[vector[[n]]*Basis[n - 1, x], {n, 1, Length[vector]}]

ddappx[vector_, x_] := Derivative[0, 2][approx][vector, x]
```

....

```
approx[{0, 0, 1, 1}, x]
```

returns correctly:

```
-1 - 3 x + 2 x^2 + 4 x^3



 ddappx[{0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, x]
```

returns incorrectly:

```
0
```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function representing the derivative as follows:

```
ddappx[vector_, x_] := Derivative[2][approx[vector, #] &][x]
```

`Derivative` is the form in which your definition *would* have been stored had you done

```
Clear[approx1, vector, x]

ddappx[vector_,x_] = D[approx1[vector, x], {x, 2}]
```

> $\text{approx1}^{(0,2)}(\text{vector
>    },x)$

(i.e., defined the function in terms of some generic unassigned symbols first - using `Set`). But the first definition using `SetDelayed` works independently of whether you had a previous definition for `approx`. `D` gets converted to `Derivative` when applied to generic functions, and `Derivative` itself acts like a function to which you can supply variables, in this case `vector` and `x`.

In your case, there was another problem because `vector` as an argument in the derivative is actually interpreted as a *list* of additional function arguments, so that the variable `x` doesn't get counted as variable slot number `2` in general. If the vector has four elements, e.g., then the variable `x` is counted as the *fifth* slot of the function for the purposes of differentiation. In order to circumvent this slot counting problem, I would supply the function `approx` to the derivative in the form of a single-argument function, which is done by the using anonymous function `approx[vector, #] &`.

Comment: Thankyou! You have done everything I asked because you solved that error...however I had already tried it this way and it gave a different problem. I will have to put it in an edit I think to explain

Comment: OK, thanks for adding the missing definition of `Basis` - that allowed me to actually try your code... and I think the updated `ddappx` should work for you.

Comment: Thankyou that works perfectly :)