# Define function that differentiates w.r.t. its argument before assigning a value

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

If I define

```
f[x_, j_] = D[E^x^2, {x, j}];
```

and then evaluate

```
f[0, 2]
```

I get the error

> General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable.

How can I tell Mathematica to evaluate the derivative first before setting $x = 0$?

Comment: You could use `Derivative[2][E^#^2 &][0]` or more generally `Derivative[2][E^#^2 &][x]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Just tested this. For some reason this increases evaluation time almost 5x. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/evaluating-derivatives-for-use-in-solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rules :

```
In[18]:= f[x1_, j_] := D[E^x^2, {x, j}] /. x -> x1

In[19]:= f[0, 2]

Out[19]= 2
```

Comment: It is better to localize dummy variable, i.e. ``f[x_, j_] := Module[{dummy}, D[E^dummy^2, {dummy, j}] /. dummy->x]``, otherwise one can get an error if  `x` is defined somewhere before.