# Evaluating partial derivative at a point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function in 5 variables, `lkl`, and I want to evaluate its second derivative wrt `tau` at a point. (I will also later want the mixed partials.) Here is my function and its second partial:

```
lkl[\[Mu]_, \[Tau]_, s_, crit_, 
  y_] := -Log[Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 + s^2]*Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]] - {0.5*
    Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 + s^2]^(-2)*(y - \[Mu])^2} - 
  Log[CDF[
    NormalDistribution[0, 1], (crit*s - \[Mu])/Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 + s^2]]]

d22 := D[lkl[\[Mu], \[Tau], s, crit, y], {\[Tau], 2}]
```

Following the top answer [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/evaluating-a-derivative-at-a-point-in-mathematica.753225/), I first tried to evaluate the derivative as follows:

```
d22 /. {\[Mu] -> 0.1, \[Tau] -> 1, s -> .5, crit -> 1.96, y -> 0.5}
```

but this yields

```
General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.
```

as well as the output:
$$\partial_{\{1,2\}}\{-0.851658\}$$

The -0.851658 is actually the value of `lkl` itself evaluated at this point, which is obviously a problem, but I don't know how to fix this.

Then, following the top answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/evaluating-derivatives-for-use-in-solve), I tried:

```
d22[\[Mu]_, \[Tau]_, s_, crit_, y_] := 
 Derivative[2][lkl[\[Mu], #, s, crit, y] &][\[Tau]]
```

which throws the same error, along with new one saying

```
SetDelayed: Tag D in [...] is Protected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a fresh kernel. It works fine on `V12.0.0`

[image: print]

Comment: Well, that was easy! Just for my edification as a new user, this seems to imply there were stored variables that somehow messed up the evaluation?

Comment: @half-pass yes, some underlying definitions from previous commands that got carried around and caused issues. Don't worry. It happens daily all over the world :)