# Can I speed up the following plotting code?

Tags: performance-tuning

I have the following *Mathematica* code. I do get the output graphs, but it takes like 12 seconds, on my computer. Longer still if I increase the value of `n1`.
Are there ways that can speed up the code?

```
Code1[A_, n1_] := Module[{E2},
  h = 197.327053^2;
  a = 0.65;
  r0 = 1.285;
  k0 = ((V02) 2 m/h)^0.5;
  R0 = r0 A^0.333;
  m = (A/(A + 1.00866 ))*931.49432;
      V02 = 40.5 + 0.13 A;
  z = a Sqrt[(2 m/h) (V02 - E2)];
       b = a*Sqrt[(2 m/h) (E2)];
  q1 = Sqrt[(V02 - E2)/E2];
  phi444[E_] := (z R0/a  ) - 
    Sum[ ArcTan[2 z/n] - 2 ArcTan[z/(n + b)], {n, 1.0, n1}];
  t1 = Plot[{Tan[phi444[E2]], -q1}, {E2, 0, 45.0}];
  Print[t1]]
```

Comment: Yes, you can. The slowdown is because you're evaluating the `Sum` in `phi444` at _each_ plot point, but this is unnecessary because it does not depend on the value of `E`. Instead, change the definition of `phi444` to `phi444[E_] := (...) - Evaluate@Sum[...]` (you can even do away with the function and just make it a constant.

Comment: See the second point in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1305/5), for a longer example

Comment: hi rm-rf.thanks for your reply. Oops, there is a typo error in my code. Should be phi444[E2_] actually. So parameters b & z in the SUM depend on E2 too. Since they do, is there another way to speed up the output

Comment: you may want to correct your question then

Answer (score 2):

The plot goes very quickly if you don't define phi444 as a function, but make it a simple assignment,as you did with z, b and q1. Also, I recommend you localize all the variables you make assignments to in your `Module` and not just E2.

```
code1[A_, n1_] := 
  Module[{E2, h, a, r0, k0, R0, m, V02, b, q1, phi444},
    h = 197.327053^2;
    a = 0.65;
    r0 = 1.285;
    k0 = ((V02) 2 m/h)^0.5;
    R0 = r0 A^0.333;
    m = (A/(A + 1.00866))*931.49432;
    V02 = 40.5 + 0.13 A;
    z = a Sqrt[(2 m/h) (V02 - E2)];
    b = a*Sqrt[(2 m/h) (E2)];
    q1 = Sqrt[(V02 - E2)/E2];
    phi444 = (z R0/a) - Sum[ArcTan[2 z/n] - 2 ArcTan[z/(n + b)], {n, 1.0, n1}];
    Plot[{Tan[phi444], -q1}, {E2, 0, 45.0}]]

code1[1., 10.]
```

[image: plot.png]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try my code:

```
Code2 = Function[{A, n1}, With[{h = 197.327053^2,
 a = 0.65,
 r0 = 1.285,
 k0 = ((V02) 2 m/h)^0.5,
 R0 = r0 A^0.333,
 m = (A/(A + 1.00866))*931.49432,
 V02 = 40.5 + 0.13 A},
Plot[{Tan[(a Sqrt[(2 m/h) (V02 - E2)] R0/a) - 
    Sum[ArcTan[2 a Sqrt[(2 m/h) (V02 - E2)]/n] - 
      2 ArcTan[
        a Sqrt[(2 m/h) (V02 - E2)]/(n + 
            a*Sqrt[(2 m/h) (E2)])], {n, 1.0, 
      n1}]], -Sqrt[(V02 - E2)/E2]}, {E2, 0, 45.0}]]];
```

It runs instantly on my machine. (I have some advise on optimization in Mathematica, but it wasn't asked here)

```
Code2[2, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome.