# How to plot an equation solution and its derivative

Tags: equation-solving

I've created an "ignorant code" using the functions I know.

Sure that there is a "smarter function" to solve what I need.

I think it's `Solve`, `DSolve` or `RSolve` that I should use, but I'm not sure how to structure it.

I have a circle equation:

$x^2+y^2=5$

Using `Reduce` I determine the minimum value and the maximum value of $x$ to meet the constraint $y> = 0$

```
Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5 && y >= 0, x]
```

> $-\sqrt{5}\leq x\leq \sqrt{5}$

With the function below I applied a value for $Y$

```
Last[Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 5, y]] /. Rule -> Set
```

> $\left\{\sqrt{5-x^2}\right\}$

This `Plot` represents the way a point can go

```
Plot[y, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*FormBox[SqrtBox[\(5 - \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)],
TraditionalForm]\)"}]
```

[image]

Here I present the equation of the point velocity on the path

```
velocidades = D[y, x]
```

> $-\frac{x}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$

If I am not mistaken this `Plot` represents the velocities of y with respect to the velocities of x

```
Plot[velocidades, {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*FormBox[\(-\*FractionBox[\(x\), SqrtBox[\(5 - \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)]]\),
TraditionalForm]\)"}]
```

[image]

List with velocity values ​​of $X$

```
xVelocidade = Range[0.01, Sqrt[5], 0.01];
```

List with velocity values ​​of $Y$

```
yVelocidade = velocidades /. x -> # & /@ xVelocidade // N
```

I created a list where the first column are the velocities in $X$ and in the second column the velocities in $Y$

```
listVelocidades = Transpose[{xVelocidade, yVelocidade}]
```

[image]

I created a list with the proportions between the velocities in $Y$ in relation to the velocities in $X$

```
proporção = Abs[yVelocidade/xVelocidade];
```

In the previous list I looked for which value approaches "2". This is to identify where $y = 2x$

```
Nearest[proporção, 2]
```

The line below tells me which line is the most appropriate value

```
Position[proporção, First[%]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  218 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

In the list with two columns I know where is the most appropriate proportion

```
velXvelY = 
 Extract[listVelocidades, 
  Position[proporção, First[Nearest[proporção, 2]]]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2.18 & -4.38108 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

And finally, a test to verify

```
test = velXvelY[[1, 2]]/velXvelY[[1, 1]] // Abs
```

> $2.00967$

Question:

**I found an approximate value because of my limitations. What function would you find the exact value?**

Comment: How about `Solve[velocidades == -2 x]`

Comment: I felt ignorant. Looking now I realized that it is logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it:

```
sol[x_] := Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 5, y];
Y[x_] := y /. Last[sol[x]]
Plot[Y[x], {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}]
velocidades[x_] := D[Y[x], x]
Plot[Evaluate[velocidades[x]], {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]}]
```

Regarding the reason for `Evaluate` see e.g. [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this/1304#1304) or http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Mar/msg00232.html .

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like you want to solve $|\frac{dy}{dx}|=2$.

```
Solve[Abs[velocidades[x]] == 2 && -Sqrt[5] < x < Sqrt[5]]
(* {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}} *)
```