# Why is Plot within Manipulate not evaluating here?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, warning-messages

I'm trying to get `Plot` within my `Manipulate` to evaluate, but I keep getting error messages:

```
F[x_]:= Cos[x]

Manipulate[
    Plot[
        Sum[
            ( ( D[ F[x], {x, k} ] /. x -> (π/6) )/k! ) * (x - (π/6) )^k ,
            {k, 1, terms}
        ], 
        {x, -3 π, 3 π}
    ], 
    {terms, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

It's supposed to be a *taylor series* that I can manipulate. Help is appreciated!

Edit: I'm very new to Mathematica, so I would appreciate, if you explained everything in a very simplified manner!

Comment: Try giving the variable with respect to which you're differentiating a different name than the plotting variable.  E.g., `Manipulate[
 Plot[Sum[((D[F[xx], {xx, k}] /. xx -> (\[Pi]/6))/k!)*(x - (\[Pi]/6))^
     k, {k, 1, terms}], {x, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}], {terms, 1, 100, 1}]`

Comment: Or, calculate the function before it is supplied to `Plot`, e.g. `With[{fcn = 
   Sum[((D[F[x], {x, k}] /. x -> (\[Pi]/6))/k!)*(x - (\[Pi]/6))^k, {k,1, terms}]},
 Plot[fcn, {x, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}] ]`.

Comment: 1. You forgot the constant term. 2. Add `Evaluate[]`: `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate @ Sum[(* stuff *)], (* stuff *)], (* stuff *)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correction**

As pointed out by J.M. needs k=0 term to be correct:
You can define the sum as function (and change differential variable),e.g.:

```
sum[x_, n_] := 
 Sum[((D[F[u], {u, k}] /. u -> (\[Pi]/6))/k!)*(x - (\[Pi]/6))^k, {k, 
   0, n}]
Manipulate[Plot[sum[x, n], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}], {n, Range[0,100]}]
```

This image shows manipulate works for original answer (without constant):
[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much this was so helpful. Also, just wondering, why wasn't mine working?

Comment: @Mmnoob your derivative used the same variable as your function and conflcted. Run the sum outside the `Manipulate` as you have written and try to evaluate it as your desired x and n. The errors will provide you insight. Good luck:)

Comment: You forgot the constant term, too. `Sum[(* stuff *), {k, 0, n}]`.

Comment: @J.M. I merely rewrote the OP function changing the variable of differentiation. I did not look at content. I may leave for OP to use as desired but your comment  may prompt this revelation.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you! Just one more question; if I were to implement a range for my "u" value (instead of /.u -> pi/6 I wanted u to range between -2 and 2) how would I alter my function? Much appreciated :)

Comment: `sum[x_, n_, a_] := Sum[((D[F[u], {u, k}] /. u -> a)/k!)*(x - a)^k, {k, 0, n}]` works, of course. @Mm, you might be interested in `Series[]` and `SeriesCoefficient[]`.

Comment: @J.M. of course...blunder after blunder I will delete my comment and leave yours

Comment: @Mmnoob see J.M.'s comment above for your question. My original comment forgot to replace  so to achieve: $f(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(a)}{j!}(x-a)^j$

Comment: @J.M. Thank you! How would you manipulate the a though with the sliders? Would it be just the same? Also when I did the syntax as you showed above my plot went blank. What went wrong?

Comment: @Mm, you should try it, you know... ;) Clear everything (``Clear["Global`*"]``) before you try the new code.

Comment: @Mmnoob your `s` is undefined

Comment: sum2[x_, n_, s_] := 
 Sum[((D[F[u], {u, k}] /. u -> s)/k!)*(x - s)^k, {k, 0, n}, {s, -1, 1}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[sum2[x, n, s], {x, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}], {n, 1, 100, 1}, {s, -1, 1, .5}] Now I have an error message @J.M.

Comment: Why did you add `{s, -1, 1}` to your Taylor sum, when that is supposed to be the expansion point?

Comment: @J.M. Ah that was my bad! I removed it, and now my code works! I'm going to try it with Series[ ] now! Thank you so much for the help!