# What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed when evaluating the RHS leaves it unchanged?

Tags: core-language, downvalues

I thought there was no difference between `f[a_] = 2 + a;` and `f[a_] := 2 + a;` because the resulting `DownValues[f]` are identical.

However, the `Information[f]` are different:

> Global`f

```
f[a_] = 2 + a
```

and

> Global`f

```
f[a_] := 2 + a
```

Is that difference entirely due to some flag telling how the `DownValues` arose, or do non-historical differences (like the mechanism upon calling) exist too?

Comment: try `ClearAll[f1, f2, a];a = 5; f1[a_] = 2 + a; f2[a_] := 2 + a;DownValues /@ {f1, f2}`?

Comment: I just answered something very similar [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181582/187).

Comment: @kglr I'm afraid this isn't what OP concerns, the RHS changes after evaluating in this case, which is against OP's title.

Comment: Thanks @xzczd; good point. Should have read the title first:)

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6346/1871

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is just my guess about what is going on. First, there is really an internal difference between the two approaches, as is shown in the OP. Another place where this difference manifests itself is with the function `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``:

```
Clear[f];
f[a_] = 2 + a;

Language`ExtendedDefinition[f]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[f->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{HoldPattern[f[a_]]->2+a},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{}}]

Notice the [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) instead of the [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) in the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) rule. For the [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) version:

```
Clear[g]
g[a_] := 2 + a

Language`ExtendedDefinition[g]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[g->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{HoldPattern[g[a_]]:>2+a},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{}}]

This time the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) rule uses [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed).

So, I think the real question is why the output of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) doesn't use [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule):

```
Clear[f]
f[a_] = 2 + a;

DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 2 + a}

I think the answer is that if [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) did use [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule), then the output would be confusing if `a` had acquired a value after `f` was defined. Suppose the output of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) was:

```
dv = {HoldPattern[f[a_]] -> 2 + a}
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a_]] -> 2 + a}

At some point, `a` is given a value:

```
a = 3;
```

And then, later, the user wants to know the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of `f`:

```
dv
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a_]] -> 5}

The user would be confused into thinking that the RHS of the rule was `5`, when it is really `2+a`. So, the function [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) purposefully replaces [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) with [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) to avoid this confusion. Note that an alternative was to introduce another hold-type wrapper around the output of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues), and this is actually what `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` does.

Comment: Interesting. Then, does this internal difference have any deeper influence? I guess the answer is no, but being just a normal user, I dare not affirm.

Comment: Is there a detectable difference between the two kinds of definitions though? I mean a difference in behaviour, ignoring directly checking `Definitions` or `ExtendedDefinition`.

Comment: @Szabolcs My guess is that there is no example where this difference in definitions would exhibit a difference in evaluation behavior. However, I wouldn't be surprised if somebody could come up with one.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it should be pointed out, that `DownValues` are the same, but `Definition` is still different. I guess this might be the "flag" op asked about.

`Information` displays `Definition` by calling it. While one might think `Information` only "illustrates" whatever is kept internally, then probably `Definition` really *is* what the kernel knows. Same output, but maybe a semantic difference one could say.

```
In[32]:= ClearAll[f, a]
f[a_] = a + 2
Definition[f]
f[a_] := a + 2
Definition[f]

Out[33]= 2 + a

Out[34]= Definition[f]

Out[36]= Definition[f]
```

Comment: Actually, `Information` internally calls `Definition`: `Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = x; Trace[Information[f], Definition[_]] // Flatten // FullForm`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but improved my answer to emphesize my message. Do you agree with what I now state?

Comment: Hmm… I think "what the kernel knows" is a somewhat vague description, and I tend to think `Definition` is also kind of illustration. Try the following example: `Clear[f, g, x];
f[x_] = x;
DownValues[g] = DownValues[f];
{Definition@g, UpValues@g, DownValues@g} // InputForm`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the title of the question, I can't help but notice the part about what gets evaluated and *when*:

> "What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed *when evaluating the RHS leaves it unchanged*?"

where I emphasize the later part.

I think there is a slight misunderstanding about what is the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` with regard to the time of evaluation of the *RHS*.

In the example provided, both definitions *seem* to be equivalent, especially after looking at the relevant `DownValues`-which *appear* identical- because care is *not* taken to account for the `OwnValues` of the symbol used in the definition of `f`, here `a`. Thus, it *appears* that the two definitions are equivalent, when in actual fact *they are not*.

If prior to the evaluation of the definition of `f` using `Set`, the symbol `a` had obtained a value eg by evaluating `a=-2` at a prior point, the two definitions would have had different `Information` and different `DownValues`.

For the sake of comparison, juxtapose the following definitions to the ones in the Q:

```
a = -2;
f[a_] = 2 + a;
Information[f]
DownValues[f]
```

> Global`f
>
> f[a_] = 0
>
> { HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 0 }

```
Clear[a, f] (* it's not necessary to clear a but we do it anyway. *)

f[a_] := 2 + a;
Information[f]
DownValues[f]
```

> Global`f
>
> f[a_] := 2 + a
>
> { HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 2 + a }

After evaluating the lines above, I hope it becomes clear that the two definitions *are not equivalent*.

In the case of `Set`, the *RHS* *appears* to be left unevaluated, when there are no `OwnValues` for `a`, but that is not the case!. By construction, `Set` *always* evaluates its *RHS*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as pointed out in [previous comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181591/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed-when-evaluating-the-rhs-leaves/181981#comment475035_181591), OP only concerns about cases that RHS is unchanged after evaluating, so example like `a = -2; f[a_] = 2 + a` is out of scope of this question.

Comment: I think there is also a copypaste mistake in the first example... `SetDelayed` acts as `Set`

Comment: @Johu indeed, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @xzczd I don't understand how the *RHS* of `Set` could remain unchanged in the context of the Q (without considering advanced use cases). My answer tries to convey the message that `Set` always evaluates its RHS and there's probably some misunderstanding on behalf of the OP. If you consider my answer as off topic I'll be more than happy to delete it.

Comment: Well, it seems that you've misunderstood OP's question in some way. "I don't understand how the RHS of `Set` could remain unchanged in the context of the Q. " Simplest case: `Clear[f, x]; f[x_] = x;`.

Comment: @xzczd like I say in my answer, this kind of example *is not* a case where the RHS of `Set` remains unchanged. `Set` always evaluates its RHS and it does so too in this case; it only appears as though nothing changes because `x` doesn't have eg `OwnValues` rules associated to it so that the evaluation loop doesn't have anything to replace in its place. Unless the question is actually about the scope of symbols and contexts etc. Anyway, thanks for the follow-up comment. I'm really interested to see how this Q gets resolved

Comment: Yes, `Set` evaluates its RHS, but the RHS after evaluation is the same as the one before evaluation, so it's unchanged, isn't it? From [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unchanged): "**unchanged**  
_adjective_ **staying the same**. "

Comment: would you consider something like `f[a_]=FixedPoint[# &, a]` and `f[a_]:=a` two expressions that could be used interchangeably with the ones presented, for the purposes of this question?

Comment: If you give it a thought, the Q is actually quite interesting. Take a close look at Carls answer. It is not about interchangeable use, but it is about hidden information, which makes the two different even if `DownValues` are the same!

Comment: @Johu I do believe it is an interesting question and that's why I'm not flagging it; indeed, I have read *@CarlWoll*'s answer; multiple times. Like I said in a previous comment, I'm really interested to see where this leads to.