# Manipulating a pre-defined function

Tags: function-construction, manipulate

I am having difficulty using `Manipulate` to build interactive plots.

I deal with equations that are somewhat long. I would like to define them prior to using them in `Manipulate`, and use their name in `Manipulate` instead of copying the entire equation for the function.

For example,

I can easily get the interactive plot for the following function:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, -5, 5}],  {a, 0, 10} ]
```

However, if I try the equation below, I get nothing. What am I doing wrong? I tried `func1 := Sin[a*x];`, but it doesn't change anything.

```
examplefunction = Sin[a*x];
Manipulate[Plot[examplefunction, {x, -5, 5}],  {a, 0, 10} ]
```

Comment: You are almost there. Define your function as: `examplefunction[x_, a_] := Sin[a*x];` and then you can use `Manipulate` as follows: `Manipulate[Plot[examplefunction[x, a], {x, -5, 5}], {a, 0, 10}]`. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you I got it working. I have a follow up question, if I `=`use instead of `:=`, it stills works, why?

Comment: 1. This issue is explained in the **Possible Issues** section of document of `Manipulate`. 2. `examplefunction[x_, a_] :=` and `examplefunction[x_, a_] =` are almost equivalent in this case, for an advanced discussion check the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181591/1871