# Problem in dealing with Sign function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions, complex

Let my function be $f(x)=e^{|x|}$.
I wish to find $f''(x)$, this can be done as-

$f'(x)=$sgn$(x)e^{|x|}$

$f''(x)=$sgn$(x)^2e^{|x|} =e^{|x|}$

In Mathematica, I am trying to plot $f''(x)$,  it presents an empty plot.

```
f[x_] := E^Abs[x];
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
g[x_] = D[f[x], {x, 2}]
Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Could anyone please locate the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`RealAbs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs) instead of [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs):

```
FullSimplify[
    D[Exp[RealAbs[x]],x,x],
    x ∈ Reals
]
```

> E^RealAbs[x]

Another possibility is to use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand):

```
Simplify[
    D[ComplexExpand[Exp[Abs[x]]],x,x],
    x ∈ Reals
]
```

> E^Abs[x]

Comment: RealAbs[] is not working in my computer :(

Comment: Alas! Again is not working :(

Comment: @SachinKumar What version of Mathematica?

Comment: It is  version 9.0

Comment: RealAbs was introduced in M11.1. The ComplexExpand version should work in M9. What result do you get?

Comment: Yes, It gives, E^Abs[x], But if I try to plot   Plot[D[ComplexExpand[Exp[Abs[x]], x, x], x \[Element] Reals], {x, 0, 
  2}], then it gives an error. May be I am trying to plot in a wrong way.

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. For example, see [1301](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1301/45431)

Comment: okok, I will see that. anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sachin, `Exp[Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}, 0]]` should also work in version 9 for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround for real x is to use  Sqrt[x^2] instead of Abs[x]

```
Plot[D[Exp[Sqrt[x^2]], x] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}]
```